# Trying to count unique observations in SQL using Partition By

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, partition-by

I have these two datasets:

**Conditions:** I would like to count the number of Unique Discharge_ID as Total_Discharges in my final dataset.

ICU_ID is a little bit more difficult. For PT_ID 001, what is happening is that PT 001 has 4 of the same discharge dates but 4 unique ICU_IDs. Since all of these ICU_IDs occur within 30 days of the Discharge_DT, I only want to count one of them. That is why total discharges for AZ is 1 and ICU_Admits = 1.

For PT_ID 002, I have 2 different Discharge_IDs but 1 ICU Admit that occurred within 30 days of both of the Discharge_IDs. I would like to count the Discharges as 2, and ICU_admits as 1.

**DF1:** Dataset of Discharges from hospital and admission to ICU within 30 days of Discharge_DT

| City | PT_ID | Hospital_ID | Admit_Dt | Discharge_DT | Discharge_ID | ICU_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AZ | 001 | ABC | 01-01-2021 | 01-03-2021 | 001,ABC,01-01-2021,01-03-2021 | 001,XYZ,01-05-2021,01-06-2021 |
| AZ | 001 | ABC | 01-01-2021 | 01-03-2021 | 001,ABC,01-01-2021,01-03-2021 | 001,XYZ,01-08-2021,01-09-2021 |
| AZ | 001 | ABC | 01-01-2021 | 01-03-2021 | 001,ABC,01-01-2021,01-03-2021 | 001,XYZ,01-11-2021,01-11-2021 |
| AZ | 001 | ABC | 01-01-2021 | 01-03-2021 | 001,ABC,01-01-2021,01-03-2021 | 001,XYZ,01-15-2021,01-16-2021 |
| CA | 002 | DEF | 04-03-2021 | 04-07-2021 | 001,ABC,04-03-2021,04-07-2021 | 002,LMN,04-27-2021,04-27-2021 |
| CA | 002 | DEF | 04-20-2021 | 04-21-2021 | 001,ABC,04-20-2021,04-21-2021 | 002,LMN,04-27-2021,04-27-2021 |

**DF desired:**

| City | TotalDischarges | ICU_Admit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AZ | 1 | 1 |
| CA | 2 | 1 |

Current Code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #edit1

WITH CTE_df1 as (
select * from df1
)
select 
        City,
        PT_ID,
        Hospital_ID,
        Admit_Dt,
        Discharge_DT,
        Discharge_ID,
        count(ICU_ID) over (partition by ICU_ID) as ICU_Pts,
        count(distinct Discharge_ID) as Total_Discharges
into #edit1
from CTE_df1
group by City, Discharge_ID, ICU_ID, PT_ID
order by City,



;with CTE_edit1 as (
select * from #edit1
)
select City, sum(ICU_Pts), sum(Total_Discharges)
from CTE_edit1
group by City
order by City
```

Current Output: PT_ID 001 works great but PT_ID 002 shows up at 2 in ICU_Admit as it is counting both as unique ICU visits.

| City | TotalDischarges | ICU_Admit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AZ | 1 | 1 |
| CA | 2 | 2 |

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: select distinct * from df1, then do select count(...) group by City over that?

Comment: This was exactly it. I was missing the distinct inside the CTE. Thank you so much!